# openFDA API - ingredient and product name queries give bad results - is it me?

Tags: api, openfda, drugs

Try running this query:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?&search=generic_name=hydrocodone - returns Oxycontin, not Norco or other hydrocodone containing drugs
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?&search=brand_name=norco - returns inhaled nitrogen product

I've tried a number of variations here, but all name/ingredient queries return strange and unintended results.
Am I writing my queries incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be using the wrong query syntax for the openFDA API.

Try: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?&search=generic_name:hydrocodone

Note the `:` instead of the `=` in the `search` value. More details are provided at https://open.fda.gov/api/#query-syntax

Comment: Thought I tried that already; but I guess I didn't.  Thank you!